# how to let users only edit/delete their own items? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Need someone's expertise, having a massive headache trying to set users ability to only edit or delete an item(ad) that they have created.

At the moment, I have it as whoever is signed in can edit/delete etc. I had some of the code in place to try the above but I had too many errors, I ended up reverting to my last working build.

index.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

 <div id="itemsContainer">



      <% @items.each do |item| %>
      <div class="itemhols">
      <%= link_to (image_tag item.image_url, size: '200x200', :class => "itemholsIm"), item %>
       <h1><%= item.city_country %></h1>
         <p><%= item.title %></p>
       <p>Price per night <%= number_to_currency(item.Price,:unit => "€") %>
       <p>
          <%= link_to 'Show', item %>
       <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_path(item) %>
          <%= link_to 'Destroy', item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }%>
       <% end %>
          <a href="/cart/<%= item.id %>" class="button">Add To Cart</a>
       </p>

      </div>
    <% end %>

</div>


<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= link_to 'Rent a Home', new_item_path, :class =>"button", :role=>"button" %>
<% end %>
```

items_controller.rb

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /items
  # GET /items.json
  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end

  # GET /items/1
  # GET /items/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /items/new
  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  # GET /items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /items
  # POST /items.json
  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.update(item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /items/1
  # DELETE /items/1.json
  def destroy
    @item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to items_url, notice: 'Item was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_item
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:city_country, :title, :image_url, :Price)
    end
end
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Just looking at the items controller it doesn't look like it is set up with a relationship that items `belong_to` a user.  Do you have any relationships set up in the models?  That is how you would do this. Can you post your code from items model and users model please?

Comment: The answer below is what you need.  I suspect you also need to create the references for this relationship in the DB as well.  You would do that by running `rails g migration add_user_reference_to_items user:references` . and then, of course, `rake db:migrate` . That will set up a user_id column in the items table, which youwill need to populate with the creators ID to get this relationship working.

Answer (score 4):

This is known as authorizing a resource.

Given the following assocations:

```
class User
  has_many :items
end

class Item
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Let start by associating the item with a user on creation:

```
def create
  @item = current_user.items.new(item_params)
  # ...
end
```

Then lets setup a before_action on `:update, :edit, :destroy` which checks if the item belongs to the current user and redirects the user if they are not authorized:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user, except: [:show, :index]
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authorize_item, only: [:update, :edit, :destroy]

  # ...
  private  
     # ...
     def authorize_item
       unless @item.user == current_user 
         redirect_to items_path, error: 'You are not authorized'
       end
     end
end
```

Of course you really don't need to be reinventing the wheel here. Use the [Pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) or [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gem.